# How can I setup ~/.tidyrc file for XML?

Tags: xml

How do you configure `tidy` to parse XML instead of HTML?

**Explanation**:
A while ago, a co-worker showed me a trick to use `tidy` to clean up XML.

Apparently, you create a `tidyrc` file like so:

```
input-xml: yes
quiet: yes
indent: yes
indent-attributes: yes
indent-spaces: 4
char-encoding: utf8
wrap: 0
wrap-asp: no
wrap-jste: no
wrap-php: no
wrap-sections: no
```

Even after adding this to `~/.tidyrc` , `tidy` is still attempting to parse as the default HTML, and not XML:

```
$ cat -v foo.out | tidy > foo.xml
line 3 column 1 - Error: <data> is not recognized!
line 3 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 3 column 1 - Warning: discarding unexpected <data>
```

I've tried various permissions:

```
[root@mongo-test3 tmp]# ls -ial ~
 51562 -rw-------  1 root root 11550 Jul 16 02:17 .bash_history
 50973 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    18 May  1 00:40 .bash_logout
 51538 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   176 May  1 00:40 .bash_profile
 51537 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   124 May  1 00:40 .bashrc
 51561 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   164 Jul 16 22:16 .tidyrc
```

I've tried naming the file `.tidyrc` and just `tidyrc`

**Versions**:
I've tried this on both MacOS and Cent 6.4

Mac OSX 10.8.4

> Darwin spuders-macbook-pro 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed
>   May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

CentOS 6.4

> Linux mongo-test3 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46
>   UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Research**:
Normally I would ask the person who taught me this trick, but they are incommunicable.

- http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/release-notes.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/tidy

**Workaround**:
As a work around, I can use the `-xml` flag, but I would prefer to get the `tidyrc` working:

```
$ cat -v foo.out | tidy -xml foo.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look through the man page for `tidy` you'll notice a comment that says the following:

> Name of the default configuration file. This should be an absolute
>   path, since you will probably invoke tidy from different directories.
>   The value of `HTML_TIDY` will be parsed after the compiled-in default
>   (defined with `-DTIDY_CONFIG_FILE`), but before any of the files
>   specified using `-config`.

So it would appear that `tidy` has a compile time option where it can be hard coded to look for specific configuration files, as you're attempting to do.

Looking through some of `tidy`'s [online documentation on Raggett's page](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) I came across this blurb:

> Alternatively, you can name the default config file via the
>   environment variable named "HTML_TIDY". Note this should be the
>   absolute path since you are likely to want to run Tidy in different
>   directories. You can also set a config file at compile time by
>   defining CONFIG_FILE as the path string, see `platform.h`.

So after downloading the source for `tidy` and looking inside the file `platform.h` I found the following lines:

```
/* #define TIDY_CONFIG_FILE "/etc/tidy_config.txt" */ /* original */
/* #define TIDY_CONFIG_FILE "/etc/tidyrc" */
/* #define TIDY_CONFIG_FILE "/etc/tidy.conf" */

/*
  Uncomment the following #define if you are on a system
  supporting the HOME environment variable.
  It enables tidy to find config files named ~/.tidyrc if 
  the HTML_TIDY environment variable is not set.
*/
/* #define TIDY_USER_CONFIG_FILE "~/.tidyrc" */
```

If you know C/C++, all these lines are commented out, so in effect the `tidy` that I have has all the options to make use of a config file disabled. I also double checked the package that was built for my Fedora 14 system to make sure that the package file form which the package was built (`tidy.spec`) didn't have any `configure` commands that would override the above configurations in the `platform.h`. I found no such overrides.

Therefore it would appear that the stock `tidy` doesn't have the ability to look for a configuration file of any sort.

#### So what are your options?

Well you can still provide `tidy` the configuration file as part of the command line:

```
$ ... | tidy -config ~/.tidyrc > foo.xml
```

Additionally you could make use of another feature of `tidy` that may have gone unnoticed above, its ability to make use of an environment variable `HTML_TIDY`. It needs to be a absolute path, so you can't use "~/.tidyrc" but you could do this:

$ export HTML_TIDY="$HOME/.tidyrc"
$ cat -v foo.out | tidy > foo.xml

If you want to make that variable permanent, just add it to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file:

```
export HTML_TIDY="$HOME/.tidyrc"
```

#### References

- [Information for build tidy-0.99.0-20.20091203.fc13 - Fedora](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=144505)
- [tidy man page](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html)
- [Dave Raggett's tidy page](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I actually noticed the HTML_TIDY parameter you mentioned just minutes before you posted this. Adding that to my path did the trick!

Comment: That's an amazingly thorough answer.